# Объединения таблиц, работают по разному

Tags: php, sql

Мне надо вывести статьи, которые относятся ко 2 категории, если напишу, через запятую, то работает, как надо

```
 SELECT question.name, category.name AS cat_name, 
            question.id,
            question.user_name,
            question.data, 
            question.status, 
            question.answer, 
            question.user_email  
FROM question, category WHERE category.id = 2  AND question.cat_id = 2 GROUP BY question.name
```

А если использую JOIN, то выводит нужные статьи, но не выводит нужную категорию, то есть всегда выводит 1 категорию, то есть AND question.cat_id = 2 не работает, почему?

```
SELECT question.name, category.name AS cat_name, 
            question.id,
            question.user_name,
            question.data, 
            question.status, 
            question.answer, 
            question.user_email  
FROM question INNER JOIN category ON cat_id = 2 AND question.cat_id = 2 GROUP BY question.name
```

Comment: Не похоже, что бы первый запрос работал как надо. ни в одном из запросов у вас нет условия объединения таблиц, т.е. некого равенства `category.X=question.Y`, а без него вы получаете перемножение всех записей одной таблицы на все записи второй. Причем, когда условие по первой таблице написано в предложении `ON` оно не работает для всех строк, так как считается условием объединения, а не выборки

Comment: Я разобрался, надо вместо ON cat_id = 2 AND question.cat_id = 2  написать ON category.id = 2 AND question.cat_id = 2

Comment: А чем JOIN лучше, чем запятая?

Comment: По хорошему ни чем, в документации на большинство СУБД написано, что INNER JOIN (а он по умолчанию именно INNER) и запятая - синонимы. Правда есть разница в работе условий в ON и в WHERE. вы же во втором случае могли написать WHERE вместо ON и получить то же что и в первом случае. Разница начинается по хорошему только кода JOIN становится например LEFT. И кстати в той же документации рекомендуется всегда условия с константами писать в WHERE, а в ON только условия объединения (что правда не совсем так :) )

Comment: Про разницу между JOIN и запятой (на английском): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Comment: Сейчас принято писать так: `FROM question Q 
INNER JOIN category C ON Q.cat_id = C.id 
WHERE Q.cat_id = 2`